# How to resolve "Error: could not receive data from server" - database connection in r?

Tags: r, postgresql

I am running into

> Error: could not receive data from server: Software caused connection abort (0x00002745/10053)

upon trying to connect to a postgres database using the `DBI` package in R. Note that i am in a work environment, so subject to a corporate firewall. Can that explain the error or is there something else that could be happening?

Here is the code I'm using

```
# Connect to trayaway dev
con <- DBI::dbConnect(
  RPostgres::Postgres(),
  host = host, port = 5432, dbname = "postgres",
  user = user, password = password
)
```

error below:

```
Error: could not receive data from server: Software caused connection abort (0x00002745/10053)
```

Comment: did you chek if ``RPostgres::Postgres()`` available?

Answer (score 1):

solution was found- i tried the same code using wiFi and the code works - when hardwired, connection string fails to connect to database - so this is a corporate firewall issue - thank you,